# Allowing the specific format of email address in MVC input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email-validation

I have a page in MVC  where i want to take the email adddress as the input which can be of format like:"`Jone Davi" <jone@gmail.com>`, "`Ben Miller" <ben@gmail.com>`, "`Jane Ton" <jane@gmail.com>`,

Then from this I want to parse the valid emailaddress.But on click of the submit button getting error message" **A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client "**

Thus is there any way to take the input of email address in above format and bypass the security error for that specific page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your controller action look like? And do you retrieve this value directly from Request.Form or from an input argument to the action method?

Comment: I have a controller and have added the code under the script tag on the View.Reading the value using Request.Form.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the angle-brackets. Use `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead.

Check out [this article](http://alexscordellis.blogspot.com/2008/12/html-escaping-in-aspnet-mvc.html) for more details on escaping HTML in ASP.net MVC.